# How to use html tags inside Primefaces currentPageReportTemplate?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to have a current pager to wrap counts in spans (for testing purposes)

so I tried

`<p:dataTable currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord} - {endRecord} of <span>{totalRecords}</span> items">`

and found that tags are escaped. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the source code for PrimeFaces 5.0, and the least that I can say is that what you're trying to do is not going to be trivial.

In essence the behavior you witness is caused by the [`CurrentPageReportRenderer`](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/paginator/CurrentPageReportRenderer.java). It writes out the current page report using this call to the [`ResponseWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html):

```
writer.writeText(output, null);
```

The API documentation for this method shows why your markup is being escaped:

> Write an object, after converting it to a String (if necessary), and
>   after performing any escaping appropriate for the markup language
>   being rendered.

If you could somehow replace that call with the one below, your markup would be preserved:

```
writer.write(output);
```

It would be fairly trivial to extend the `CurrentPageReportRenderer` and override the `render` method, but wiring your custom renderer into PrimeFaces will prove to be a lot more challenging.

JSF does allow specifying custom renderers in the `faces-config.xml`, but this happens at the component level. The default renderer used for the data table component is the [`DataTableRenderer`](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java), which extends the [`DataRenderer`](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/DataRenderer.java), which in turn does its magic with the `CurrentPageReportRenderer`.

This means that you would have to provide a custom implementation of the `DataTableRenderer`, in which you would have to override `DataRenderer`'s `encodePaginatorMarkup` method where you plug in your custom `CurrentPageReportRenderer`. Then you would have to set up your `faces-config.xml` to tell JSF to use your renderer implementation instead of the one provided by PrimeFaces.

```
<renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>org.example.MyDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

All in all, it wouldn't be that hard to do, but the solution would be fairly fragile, and any significant changes in future versions of the aforementioned classes are liable to break your customization.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there might be a simple way :) writing a custom renderer is OK for me